# Can I group in google sheets for visual ease, without aggregating?

Tags: google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-formula, grouping

I have a sheet of voters and I want to make the list easy to read for campaigners who will be knocking on doors.

```
Address          Name          Affiliation
1 Oak St         John Smith    D
1 Oak St         Mary Smith    U
2 Oak St         George Jones  D
3 Oak St         Anna Johnson  R
3 Oak St         Tom Lee       U
4 Oak St         Ellen Lewis   U
```

I want it to be grouped by address, so the people knocking on doors can easily see who is in the household. I want it to look something like this:

```
Address          Name          Affiliation
1 Oak St         John Smith    D
                 Mary Smith    U

2 Oak St         George Jones  D

3 Oak St         Anna Johnson  R
                 Tom Lee       U

4 Oak St         Ellen Lewis   U
```

I don't want to aggregate in any way, but I want to group by address.

I have tried adding a new column to the left and doing

```
=IF(B3=B2,"",CHAR(10))
```

which weirdly only works for the top few rows and then doesn't work for all the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You may try:

```
=let(Σ,unique(tocol(A2:A,1)), reduce(A1:C1,sequence(counta(Σ)),lambda(a,c,{a;
       let(Λ,filter(B:C,A:A=index(Σ,c)),Γ,counta(index(Λ,,1))-1,
       {if(Γ=0,index(Σ,c),{index(Σ,c);wrapcols(,Γ,)}),Λ;wraprows(,3,)})})))
```

[image]